# Irregular table divs

Tags: html, css

I would like to put the last div on each row, under the row. Is it possible to achieve this without breaking `display: table`? I don't want to add the second row for this. I tried to explain my problem on the image below
[image]

My html

```
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>id</td>
                                <td>creator</td>
                                <td>receiver</td>
                                <td>start_date</td>
                                <td>end_date</td>
                                <td>daily_pay</td>
                                <td>total_votes</td>
                                <td>permlink</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>aaaabbbb</td>
                                <td>aaaabbbb</td>
                                <td>
                                    {new Date(
                                        '2015-05-01T00:00:00'
                                    ).toLocaleString()}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {new Date(
                                        '2019-06-01T00:00:00'
                                    ).toLocaleString()}
                                </td>
                                <td>100.000</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>testing stuff</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>aaaabbbb</td>
                                <td>aaaabbbb</td>
                                <td>
                                    {new Date(
                                        '2015-05-01T00:00:00'
                                    ).toLocaleString()}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {new Date(
                                        '2019-06-01T00:00:00'
                                    ).toLocaleString()}
                                </td>
                                <td>100.000</td>
                                <td>0</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
                                    adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit amet
                                    ipsa adipisci praesentium unde, illum
                                    iure fuga necessitatibus dolorem. Sed
                                    ipsam facilis modi eligendi cumque
                                    maiores quae repellat incidunt error!
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: show your html please

Comment: It looks like you might want this cell as a new row that spans 8 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be most semantic if you made the last cell a `<td>` within a new `<tr>` spanning all 8 columns via `colspan`.

```css
tbody td {
  padding: .5em;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>creator</th>
      <th>receiver</th>
      <th>start_date</th>
      <th>end_date</th>
      <th>daily play</th>
      <th>total votes</th>
      <th>permalink</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>aaaaaaaa</td>
      <td>bbbbbbbb</td>
      <td>mike n</td>
      <td>01/15/2000</td>
      <td>01/15/2001</td>
      <td>1000.00</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore quod officiis nostrum provident distinctio consequatur nobis vero vel dignissimos magnam. Harum velit mollitia veniam, provident, labore repellat beatae nisi error!
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>aaaaaaaa</td>
      <td>bbbbbbbb</td>
      <td>mike n</td>
      <td>01/15/2000</td>
      <td>01/15/2001</td>
      <td>1000.00</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore quod officiis nostrum provident distinctio consequatur nobis vero vel dignissimos magnam. Harum velit mollitia veniam, provident, labore repellat beatae nisi error!
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly remove last td text which you want to comes after all tr, create a new tr after the permlink and add a td which you want to show in full width, kindly see my suggestion.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>id</td>
      <td>creator</td>
      <td>receiver</td>
      <td>start_date</td>
      <td>end_date</td>
      <td>daily_pay</td>
      <td>total_votes</td>
      <td>permlink</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>aaaabbbb</td>
      <td>aaaabbbb</td>
      <td>
        {new Date( '2015-05-01T00:00:00' ).toLocaleString()}
      </td>
      <td>
        {new Date( '2019-06-01T00:00:00' ).toLocaleString()}
      </td>
      <td>100.000</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>
      </td>
      <!-- <td>testing stuff</td> -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8">testing stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>aaaabbbb</td>
      <td>aaaabbbb</td>
      <td>
        {new Date( '2015-05-01T00:00:00' ).toLocaleString()}
      </td>
      <td>
        {new Date( '2019-06-01T00:00:00' ).toLocaleString()}
      </td>
      <td>100.000</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit amet ipsa adipisci praesentium unde, illum iure fuga necessitatibus dolorem. Sed ipsam facilis modi eligendi cumque maiores quae repellat incidunt error!</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```